# PHP code inside shortcodes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, echo, shortcode

Basically, I have this line of code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[O_U user_name="operator" 
blocked_message="This page is restricted for guests."] 
**Content Goes here** [/O_U]'); ?>
```

Now, inside Content Goes here I use regular HTML to create my content. But, now I need to add some php inside that HTML.

Right now, I need to populate the *option* for **select** tag with MySQL results.

I have a php code:

```
<?php
    $database_name = "rams";
    $mydb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $database_name, DB_HOST);
    $mydb -> show_errors();

    //Populate languages
    $languages = $mydb -> get_results(
        'SELECT * FROM language_skills'
    );

    foreach ($languages as $language){
       //do some echo of html
    }
?>
```

How can I achieve a result here? I now, echo waits for a string there. I thought about heredoc and a custom function, but I can't seem to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just close PHP tag before //do some echo of html, then open like this

```
<?php
    $database_name = "rams";
    $mydb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $database_name, DB_HOST);
    $mydb -> show_errors();

    //Populate languages
    $languages = $mydb -> get_results(
        'SELECT * FROM language_skills'
    );

    foreach ($languages as $language){ ?>
       <!--Write your html hear--> 
       <option><?=$language?></option>
    <?}
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying but after "$mydb -> " in show errors line everything just turns into html text in a browser. I see from show_errors() and till the end.

Comment: try to remove that line

Comment: it's not about the line, rather it's about "->"